# CSS: Detect input with valid data not focused with no javascript

Tags: html, css

I have been checking similar questions in Stackoverflow, but I can't find the proper way to do this:

I want an input without border. When focused, border is blue. Also, when not focused but with text added inside it, border should be blue as well.

I am trying with `.Input:focus, .Input:not(:focus):valid {}`, with no result: the rule is triggered when the inut is not focused or with text, I add an example:

```css
.Input {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}
.Input:focus,
.Input:not(:focus):valid {
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="Input" type="text" name="EMAIL" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

Any idea will be welcome!

Comment: NOTE: `:valid` concerns your input type, if it's text, it's valid even if empty (empty string is valid text). I know no method so far to do this only in CSS

Comment: @SimpleBeat Thanks, but this is a solution for another problem; which anyway, seem to fail to match an empty input.

Comment: It is not possible with CSS alone - not cross-browser anyway. Closest would be to use the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
.Input[value=""], .Input:placeholder-shown {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.Input, .Input:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

By default, the input field will always have a blue border. The two selectors above it, however, will determine whether to show the border or not.

If the input field has an empty value, or if the placeholder text is displaying, then the border will be removed and the field will have no decoration. Otherwise, if the input doesn't match any of this criteria, it will have a blue border.

The `:focus` attribute is used to ensure that the field will have a blue border when it is selected but doesn't contain any text, or when it only contains placeholder text.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm, yes, the closest thing will be `:placeholder-shown`… Not fully supported, but is the closest thing without JS.

Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`:valid` works when the content of the input passes all validation rules placed on it. In your case, since it is an email, you can change the type from text to email. Any text entered into the input that doesn't match the default HTML Email pattern won't trigger the `:valid` pseudo class.

In order for your input to be "invalid" when it is empty you can add `required` to your input. Since it is defaulted to being empty it will not be valid as it is required.

```css
.Input {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}
.Input:focus,
.Input:not(:focus):valid {
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="Input" type="email" required name="EMAIL" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

Additionally you can use the `pattern` attribute which accepts a Javascript regex string to validate your input on. For example purposes only you can use a pattern like `[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$`. By default the input is empty and is invalid. Same goes for any string that doesn't match `something@something.com` or `something123@something123.eu` as examples.

```css
.Input {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}
.Input:focus,
.Input:not(:focus):valid {
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="Input" type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required name="EMAIL" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

Comment: Yes, that's true, adding a required solve the problem… I didn't say that I didn't wanted the field as required, but this will work in this case.

Thanks!